# How can I enable Gzip on my site and test it?

Tags: css, .htaccess, curl, compression, gzip

## Goal

I'm new to the world of compression. 
I would like to enable the gzip compression for my website.I'm not sure how will accomplish that the right way.

---

## I've tried

- create `.htaccess` in the `root/` directory of my site and add these lines :

  `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript`

---

## Test using cURL

I tried run `curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' http://my-site.com`

Result :

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0    20    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:30 --:--:--     0
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

**Note** : Content-Encoding: gzip

---

## Test using GZip Testing Online Tool

I go this site and enter my URL.

http://checkgzipcompression.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bunlongheng.com%2F

Result : `You're blessed! It's GZIP Enabled.`

I also test on : https://www.feedthebot.com/tools/gzip/

Result : Gzip working? `Yes` reducing file size by 71.6%

---

## Browsers

I've tried on : Safari, Firefox, and Chrome.

After passing 2 tests, I thought, I did it correctly, but when I go to my site : My styles all screw up. Feel free to see it : [here](http://www.bunlongheng.com/)

My console keep giving me this error :

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

---

Can someone please explain why is this happening ?

Do I need to configure anything in my `php.ini` ? 
If so, I might need to create one because I don't have that.

**Any helps will be really appreciated.**

Comment: If you don't get some replies, you may want to use the `flag` link at the bottom of your question and ask the moderator to move this Q to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna suppose that you are using an Apache Web Server. You have to add into your .htaccess these lines:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

To check if GZip is enabled you can use this tool:
https://www.feedthebot.com/tools/gzip/

Comment: I've tried that also, but it isn't working either. Should I contact my host provider for this ? I created `.htaccess` my self. Am I suppose to do that ?

Comment: But when I test my URL, I got it to be positive.

Comment: Is possible that your host provider have disabled this functionallity. This can be configured on the php.ini by adding these lines: 
`
output_buffering = Off
output_handler =
zlib.output_compression = Off
`

Comment: I tried add that in, and I got `Internal Server Error`